# Change Font Awesome Icon Using Css

Tags: css

HTML here

```
<div class="col-sm down-arrow">
  <i class="fas fa-arrow-right"></i>
</div>
```

I can do it with Javascript

```
var width = $(window).width();
if (width <= 768) {
    $('.down-arrow').find('.fas').removeClass('.fas fa-arrow-right').addClass('.fas fa-arrow-down');
}
else
    $('.down-arrow').find('.fas').removeClass('.fas fa-arrow-down').addClass('.fas fa-arrow-right');
```

But I want to do it with Css, because it can't responsive when change screen size smaller than 768 px

I have try use content:"\f063" font-family:FontAwesome

But it doesn't work

Please help

Thank you

Comment: `FontAwesome` is the incorrect `font-family` See: https://fontawesome.com/v5.15/how-to-use/on-the-web/advanced/css-pseudo-elements

Comment: You can use onresize event. When it occurs, you do your javascript again.
https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onresize.asp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do this with only CSS and media query. I've used this method myself, although I'll be the first to admit this is ***not really the best practice***. So, keep that in mind.

The idea is to set the font awesome conditions on a custom class and then change the `before` value according to the screen width.

```css
.sudo-fa-arrow {
  font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Free";
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  display: inline-block;
  font-style: normal;
  font-variant: normal;
  text-rendering: auto;
  line-height: 1;
  font-weight: 900;
}
.sudo-fa-arrow::before {
  content: "\f061"; /* The right arrow */
}
@media (max-width:768px) {
  .sudo-fa-arrow::before {
    content: "\f063"; /* The down arrow */
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.4/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="col-sm down-arrow">
  <i class="sudo-fa-arrow"></i>
</div>
```

Comment: I run code snippet the arrow always down..

Comment: @HoBunCheung That's because the container's width is smaller that 768 pixels. Click the "full page" link to expand the container.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way do with Javascript.

Just add an EventListener with 'resize'

Here is the javascript code:

```
window.addEventListener('resize', ChangeIcon);
function ChangeIcon(){
    var width = $(window).width();
    if (width <= 768) {
        $('.down-arrow').find('.fas').removeClass('.fas fa-arrow-right').addClass('.fas fa-arrow-down');
    }
    else
        $('.down-arrow').find('.fas').removeClass('.fas fa-arrow-down').addClass('.fas fa-arrow-right');
}
```